# Correct selector for append

Tags: javascript, jquery

What selector should I use to append val for the div in which is input form, not all the divs?
Divs are many and they are the same, so I cant just use class or id.

```
$("input").focusout(function(event){
             $("div").append($(this).val());
};
```

Comment: Eeh what? I don't get it.

Comment: you need to provide more information. atleast give an idea of the html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input").on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('div').append($this.val());
})
```

**Edit** Just to clarify the code:

Since I think OP just wants to show values in div when info is modified, a best event is `change` over `focusout`.

`var $this = $(this);` is used because some times selectors can be expensive then I'm "caching" the object to can be used before. `$this` is just a variable name.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you please explain me briefly what is it for `var $this = $(this);`?

Comment: I've added the explain in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Find the closest form element, then search for the div within that form.

```
$(this).closest('form').find('div').append($(this).val());
```